# python plotly dashtable convert link to hyperlink

Tags: python, hyperlink, plotly, plotly-dash

i am looking for a solution to convert a link to a clickable link in a dataframe which I displayed in a plotly dashboard (table)

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dash_table
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()
df['links_test'] = ""
df['links_test'].iloc[0] = '../quantstats/all_trades.html'

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row(
        dash_table.DataTable(


            df.to_dict('records'), [
                {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns], fixed_rows={'headers': True, },

            id="datatable",
        ),

    ),
])
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I expect that the column "links_test" rows are clickable and open a local html file. thanks for ideas"

Comment: Solution on plotly community forum: https://community.plotly.com/t/a-hyper-link-in-datatable-cell-content/48412/3

Comment: Thank you, still trying to implement it into my code....